# elasticsearch v5 template to v6

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, kibana-6, amazon-cloudtrail

I am currently running elasticsearch cluster version 6.3.1 on AWS and here is template file which I need to upload but can't 
```

```
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "_all" : {"enabled" : true, "omit_norms" : true},
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "message_field" : {
          "match" : "message",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "enabled" }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "string_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "enabled" },
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "doc_values" : true, "ignore_above" : 256}
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "float_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "float",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "float", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "double_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "double",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "double", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "byte_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "byte",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "byte", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "short_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "short",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "short", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "integer_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "integer",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "integer", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "long_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "long",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "long", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "date_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "date",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "date", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      }, {
        "geo_point_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "geo_point",
          "mapping" : { "type" : "geo_point", "doc_values" : true }
        }
      } ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date", "doc_values" : true },
        "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed", "doc_values" : true },
        "geoip"  : {
          "type" : "object",
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "ip": { "type": "ip", "doc_values" : true },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point", "doc_values" : true },
            "latitude" : { "type" : "float", "doc_values" : true },
            "longitude" : { "type" : "float", "doc_values" : true }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I tried loading the template via Dev Tools in Kibana and got the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: No field type matched on [float], possible values are [object, string, long, double, boolean, date, binary]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: No field type matched on [float], possible values are [object, string, long, double, boolean, date, binary]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "No field type matched on [float], possible values are [object, string, long, double, boolean, date, binary]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Can somebody please help with what I need to do to have this working on version 6 elasticsearch. I am completely new to elasticsearch and am just looking to setup logging from cloudtrail -> s3 -> AWS elasticsearch -> kibana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work on 6.3, the correct mapping for the logstash index would need to be (taken [from here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/6.x/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template-es5x.json)):

```
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "version" : 60001,
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "message_field" : {
          "path_match" : "message",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "norms" : false
          }
        }
      }, {
        "string_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "text", "norms" : false,
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 }
            }
          }
        }
      } ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date"},
        "@version": { "type": "keyword"},
        "geoip"  : {
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "ip": { "type": "ip" },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" },
            "latitude" : { "type" : "half_float" },
            "longitude" : { "type" : "half_float" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```